# loadAssocList() is not working properly when assigning a column name as the key parameter

Tags: mysql, jdatabase, joomla-3.9

I have a complex query like below. I want the `p.ComponentId` values to be the first level keys of the multidimensional result set array. However, it does not work as expected. In my case, when I don't set a key, it returns 12 items in the array as expected. When I nominate a column as the parameter of `loadAssocList()`, it only returns one (the last) item.

Am I doing something wrong?

The query is this:

```
// Get database connector
  $db = JFactory::getDbo();

 // Prepare query to get all fields
  $query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select($db->qn('t.value'))    
    ->from($db->qn('#__rsform_properties', 'p'))
    ->leftJoin($db->qn('#__rsform_components', 'c').' ON ('.$db->qn('c.ComponentId').' = '.$db->qn('p.ComponentId').')')
    ->leftJoin($db->qn('#__rsform_translations', 't').' ON (CONCAT('.$db->qn('p.ComponentId').',\'.ITEMS\') LIKE '.$db->qn('t.reference_id').')')
    ->where($db->qn('c.FormId').'='.$db->q($args['form']->FormId))
    ->where($db->qn('t.form_id').'='.$db->q($args['form']->FormId))
    ->where($db->qn('p.PropertyName').'='.$db->q('ITEMS'))
    ->where($db->qn('c.Published').'='.$db->q(1))
    ->order($db->qn('c.Order'));
 $db->setQuery($query);

  // Get all fields
  $fields = $db->loadAssocList();
```

Which returns 12 results just fine.

But when i change the last row to:

```
  $fields = $db->loadAssocList('p.ComponentId');
```

I get this result:

```
array(1) {
  [""]=>
  array(1) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(2) "Ja"
  }
}
```

I also tried `t.reference_id`, but this provides the same result.

I was expecting something like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["$key"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(2) "Ja"
  }
}
```

where `$key` would be the row's `p.ComponentId` value.

Comment: This is a solid example of a high quality question.  It shows effort and diagnostic toil.  It provides sufficient detail to reproduce the issue.  It is clear and narrow about the issue to be resolved.  Definitely an upvote-worthy question that will help future researchers -- an ideal page to be added to the "book of Joomla Stack Exchange".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most critical to fixing your issue is to include the `p.ComponentId` column in your `select()` call so that it is available at the time the result set is being constructed.

If you have your error reporting turned on/up, then I expect that you would have seen several of these:

> Notice: Undefined index: p.ComponentId in ...

I have a few additional pointers to give, so I'll start with my suggested rewrite of your database interacting script then explain what I've done and why.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query
    ->select(
        $db->qn([
            'p.ComponentId',
            't.value'
        ])
    )
    ->from($db->qn('#__rsform_properties', 'p'))
    ->innerJoin(
        $db->qn('#__rsform_components', 'c')
        . ' ON ' . $db->qn('p.ComponentId') . ' = ' . $db->qn('c.ComponentId')
    )
    ->innerJoin(
        $db->qn('#__rsform_translations', 't')
        . ' ON ' . $query->concatenate([$db->qn('p.ComponentId'), $db->q('.ITEMS')]) . ' = ' . $db->qn('t.reference_id')
        . ' AND ' . $db->qn('c.FormId') . ' = ' . $db->qn('t.form_id')
    )
    ->where([
        $db->qn('c.FormId') . ' = ' . $db->q($args['form']->FormId),
        $db->qn('p.PropertyName') . ' = ' . $db->q('ITEMS'),
        $db->qn('c.Published') . ' = 1'
    ])
    ->order($db->qn('c.Order'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$fields = $db->loadAssocList('ComponentId');
```

I would expect your result set to resemble this structure now:

```
[
    1 => [
        "ComponentId" => 1,
        "value" => "Ja"
    ],
    2 => [
        "ComponentId" => 2,
        "value" => "Nein"
    ]
]
```

1. `$db` and `$query` need to be declared at the start of this process, because these variables will be leveraged in subsequent method calls (such as `q()`, `qn()`, and `concatenate()`).
2. I've expanded the internal syntax of some of the method calls to avoid excessively wide lines of code with the intent to make the code easier to read.  You are welcome to compact the code into fewer lines if you wish, but be sure to obey [PSR-12 coding standards](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) and/or [Joomla's coding standards](https://github.com/joomla/coding-standards/tree/master/manual).
3. Because of your posted `WHERE` conditions, I can infer that `INNER JOIN` is better suited than `LEFT JOIN` because you have no interest in rows from the joined tables that lack `$args['form']->FormId` as their form identifier.  I have removed one of the `WHERE` conditions and added the necessary logic into the second `innerJoin()` call.
4. Your join `ON` conditions are sufficiently simple and do not require any parentheses to preserve the logic.  For this reason, I recommend removing the unnecessary syntax.
5. Joomla has a concatenating helper function available which will make your code more "portable" (meaning it will be instantly functional on a wide spectrum of database drivers e.g. mysqli, sqlite, sqlsrv, etc...), so I recommend employing `concatenate()`.  Unlike `$db`, it must be called from `$query` -- this is the reason that `$query` is declared as a separate variable before diving into query building syntax.  There is [a potential gotcha about the `concatenate()` call](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/24302/12352#:%7E:text=Null%20Parameters%20With%20concatenate()), but it will not impact your usage here.
6. For best performance, you must not use `LIKE` unless it is necessary.  Because there are no wildcards (`%` or `_`) in your comparison value, a simple `=` comparison is all that is required.
7. It is not beneficial to quote-wrap a `1` for your query, so I've omitted that `q()` call.
8. When you call `loadAssocList()` and feed it the desired column as its parameter / first level key, you no longer need to declare the table alias.  The result set generated by the `SELECT` will never include the table or alias that it came from.  In fact, if you had two columns in the `SELECT` that came from two different tables, but shared the same name, then the former column would be overwritten by the latter one.  In other words, make sure that your column names are uniquely identified so that you never accidentally exclude any data from the result set.
9. Before I edited your question, you referred to the result set as an array of objects, but you are calling `loadAssocList()` -- which generates an array of arrays.  If you desire an array of objects, you'll want to call `loadObjectList()` instead.  You will still be able to nominate the first level keys in the same fashion.

p.s. The reason that you were getting 1 row instead of 12 rows, was because the missing column was generating an empty value.  PHP arrays may never have duplicate keys on the same level, so every subsequent row of data was overwriting the earlier row because of the duplicated (empty string) first level key.

Comment: Wow thanks for your explanation! That answer is so elaborate! It's gold. So much to learn in that answer. Thanks!

Comment: The page is a testament to why I am so passionate/opinionated about only asking Joomla questions on Joomla Stack Exchange instead of Stack Overflow.  While it is possible that someone from SO would have provided you with resolving advice, there is an exponentially smaller chance that they would be aware of Joomla helper methods and general best practices within the CMS.  I am very appreciative that you have decided to ask your question here.